# Access only via Google?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, google-search

i have a wordpress site. I want to restrict access sources. Restriction should be people who write url or copy-paste to web browser. People should only enter via Google search results to my website.

How its possible? could you explain to me step by step ?

Comment: I don't think it is possbile.

Comment: That possible because i saw some websites. For example if you paste to Google and enter via Google this website : https://tahye.com/ You can see everything. But if you paste to webbrowser, you see only login page.

Answer (score -1):

You must work with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` value. When you access to site directly - this field is empty.

Something to play around:

```
$referer = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if (strpos($referer,"google")) {
    //FROM GOOGLE
} else {
   //OTHER WAY
}
```

Comment: Google has gone to full HTTPS, which means you won't get any referrers like this. [It's been that way for years](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59794/how-to-get-keywords-from-google-http-referrer)